# Using log4net simultaneously from /clr dll and C# dll

Tags: c#, log4net, clr

I have a DLL with `Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)` (C++/CLI) that calls into C# DLL.

Currently, I use log4net only from C# DLL. Is it possible to use the same log file from both DLLs?

I can't just expose a method for logging from C# DLL because I need to log even before C# dll was loaded.

Comment: I assume your "DLL with Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)" is a C++/CLI DLL? And sure, you should be able to set up your logging in the C++/CLI DLL (and remove it from the C# DLL), and just use `LogManager` from the C# DLL

Comment: @canton7 thank you for the direction. Will be working on it. Feel free to turn it into a proper answer.